# How to set that screen on device is on, and vibrate when notification comes?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hello I am building an app where I am using notifications. I want that when notification comes, my device vibrate and if screen is in sleep mode, than when notification comes screen is on. 
This is my notifcation builder:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.asp)
                    .setContentText(notificationData.getText())
                    .setContentTitle(notificationData.getTitle())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification.build());
```

What should I do to set vibrate and device's screen is on when notification comes?

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation of Notification @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: use **WakeLock** and **Vibrate** classes.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: This is very common question and has many tutorials out there, you can search it first before you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Vibrate device [setVibrate(long[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setVibrate(long[])) on notification builder.

```
    long[] vibrate  = {500,200,200,500};
    notification.setVibrate(vibrate);
```

To make device screen turn on, try using below code.

```
public static void turnScreenOn(int sec, final Context context)
{
        final int seconds = sec;

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();

        if( !isScreenOn )
        {
        WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MyLock");
        wl.acquire(seconds*1000);
        WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyCpuLock");
        wl_cpu.acquire(seconds*1000);
        }
 }
```

Don't forgot to add `WAKE_LOCK` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: And this function turnScreenOn I should call after that mine cod for making notification?

Comment: Yes, you can call it when you want to turn device's screen on. In your case you can put it after notify.

Comment: But I read that this FULL_WAKE_LOCK is really hard for battery...could I use just ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP?

Comment: Not an issue of battery because you are going to acquire wake lock for few seconds only not for long time.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate...Just one more question...I have commented this lines with wl_cpu and it works...Why sould I use that part of code?

Comment: If you hold a partial wake lock, the CPU will continue to run, regardless of any display timeouts or the state of the screen and even after the user presses the power button. In all other wake locks, the CPU will run, but the user can still put the device to sleep using the power button.

Comment: And just one more sorry.. what means this (seconds*1000)..  is that means how many seconds is phone awake or what?

Comment: Multiply seconds by 1000 to convert it to millisecond because method require argument in millisecond. check this [acquire()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html#acquire()) and the phone will stay awake for seconds which you have passed in first argument of `turnScreenOn(int sec, final Context context)`

Comment: `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK` is deprecated. How can it be done without it?